On an oscillatory property of the Riemann Xi-function
In their paper "The Integral of the Riemann Xi-Function", Lagarias and Montague mention Wintner's 1947 proof that
$$
\Xi^{(-1)}(t) > 0 \quad \text{when} \quad t > 0.
$$
This result implies that
$$
\Xi^{(-1)}(z)
$$
has no zeros on the positive real axis. They reference the paper as follows:
"A. Wintner, On an oscillatory property of the Riemann Xi-function, Math. Notae 7 (1947), 177–178."
However, I have been unable to locate this paper online. Could anyone recommend any books, articles, or survey papers that discuss Wintner's work on this topic? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Doesn't the discussion in the Lagarias-Montague paper, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.4348, following equation 4.4, amount to a proof?

@GerryMyerson thank you so much. Yes, they have the outline of the proof. What I want to see is how $\Phi(u)$ is decreasing. They just mention that it is proven by Wintner.
